# Simple PHP file

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  echo "<b>Hello World</b> <br />";
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

I have named the file as test.php but I dont get the desired output in my firefox 3.6 browser.

Output

```
Hello World
"; ?>
```

Comment: Any more specs? I didn't see any problem with the PHP file.

Comment: When viewing the output in Firefox, what does "View Source" show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to copied the file to a server with PHP installed? If you just try to open the file in Firefox, it'll just trying to display the whole thing as HTML, which isn't going to do what expect.

Comment: I have installed WAMP and I have copied my file to the location
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\htdocs and now I open http://localhost/test.php in my browser...still no luck

Comment: k...got the answer from superuser. I was copying it in the wrong location. I had to copy it in the www folder.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you haven't configured PHP properly. Refer to the PHP documentation and the documentation for your web server.

Comment: I have installed PHP using WAMP. Can you guide me how to configure PHP for that.

Comment: This site is for programming issues, not system administration issues.

Answer (score 0):

In a page called index.php put this code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and see what happens.